# Need to replicate EC2 machine from non-China Region to China region

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to make exact replica of my server in non China region to China region. AWS wont allow AMI copy into china, Is there a way of achieving my goal. ?

Already tried [1], but didn't worked for me. would like to hear if anyone have done [1] successfully.

[1]https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=178941

Comment: The answer in the forum post is correct.  That is exactly how this can be done.  It is essentially just making a byte-for-byte disk image of a boot volume, like we used to do in the old days of "imaging" physical servers -- set one up the way you want it, and clone its hard drive.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks. Actually setup was "LUKS Encrypted Volumes (via cryptsetup) on top of LVM" So it was not working. Took help of a friend and I was able to achieve it though good old "dd" as per forum I mentioned.

Comment: What should we do with this question?  I think I'll vote to close it as a problem that can no longer be reproduced, since the solution you didn't think was working turns out to be correct.  Note that if you're a professional administrator, as I assume you are, then you'll find [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) rather than Stack Overflow is usually a better place for similar questions.  For hobbyist and power user "general computing" (non-programming) questions, check out [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score -1):

You can easily transfer or copy your AMI to another region. There has some ways. Most easiest way is to use the `Copy AMI` options.

Click on your instance -> Create Image .

From AMI lists -> Select your newly created AMI -> Copy AMI -> Select region where you want to take it. After that it will be available in that region after couple mins. Then from that region, you can simply re-create your instance with this AMI. This is simple.

Another way is, if AWS don't allow you to copy your AMI in China region, then you just create another account in China Region and then from your AMI list, just give the permission to your china region AWS account, and it will be available in your china region account and you can re-create instance from there. Though, I never dealt with china region in AWS, but it should work.

Comment: *"Though, I never dealt with china region in AWS, but it should work."*  No, that's not correct.  There are at least 3 different, disconnected partitions of AWS: The one you're thinking of (`aws`), US GovCloud (`aws-us-gov`), and China (`aws-cn`) which currently has a single region, properly called Beijing (`cn-north-1`) rather than China.  No service interaction occurs, and no cross-partition cross-account trust is possible, since no credentials are valid across partition boundaries... so your suggestion cannot be made to work -- hence the reason for OP's question.

Comment: @shaharia, Already tried your methods and aws will not allow you. as Michael explained.